# How to pull tweets with only 1 cashtag?

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis, stock, rtweet

I am working on a project where I am pulling in Tweets using a cash tag and performing sentiment analysis on those tweets. The issue I am having is the tweets can have more than one cashtag and I want to limit to just one. I am using the R package rtweet to pull tweets from Twitter.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean 'hashtags' instead of cashtags ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'pull' here ?

Comment: cashtags are hasthags for companies on USA Stock Exchange and start with $ instead of #.  @8nracing, you can filter them by the symbols under the entities column and limit to those that have just one cashtag.